# Hiding content in Gmail and Outlook not working

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I'm trying to make an email with two links, I want to show one in Gmail only, and the second one in outlook only.
I did some search and I found that I need to use mso-hide in Outlook and display none it's enough on Gmail. none of those work. display none hide my element in outlook and Gmail and mso-hide didn't affect.
My try is:

```
<!--[if !mso 9]><!-->
<div style="mso-hide:all">
  Content 02
</div>
<!--<![endif]-->
<div style='display: none;'>
  Content 03
</div>
```

is there a solution to hide an element only on Outlook and the same with Gmail?

Comment: Have you tried inline CSS for both?

Comment: Yes I tested also inline CSS

Comment: @Syfer I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Dylan Smith has written an excellent 'How to Target Email Clients' page that goes through all known techniques for different email clients. https://howtotarget.email/

Using that, we can get the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <!--[if !mso]><!-->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <!--<![endif]-->

<style type="text/css">
u + .body .gmailshow {
    display:block!important;
}    
</style>
    </head>

<body class="body">
    <div>CONTENT EVERYWHERE</div>
<!--[if mso | ie]>
<div>
  Content OUTLOOK only
</div>
<![endif]-->
<div class="gmailshow" style="display: none;">
  Content GMAIL ONLY
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Notes:

- The body, since it gets turned into a div, requires a class (here, body)
- There was something wrong with your Outlook if statement, make sure you check that
- There is no known way to get the Gmail targetting to target Gmail IMAP, since it does not regard `<style>` blocks (this is but one version of Gmail - standard Gmail apps and Gmail webmail work with this technique)